# hide and show some div based on overflow

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, overflow

I have a dynamic table where i have hide after displaying first few words from a big text, if the user want to read the complete data he use to click **view more** button to read the complete data it works fine but the problem is how to show view more only for the rows which has overflowed text in it.

**Php solution**

simply in php we can use `strlen()` and can give condition like

```
if(strlen($data) > 100 ){
   make visible
}
```

but cant assume how many chars exactly fit in the div because users may use enter so that the text count may vary so it wont works.

**JavaScript solution**

```
function checkOverflow(el)
    {
       var curOverflow = el.style.overflow;
       if ( !curOverflow || curOverflow === "visible" )
          el.style.overflow = "hidden";
       var isOverflowing = el.clientWidth < el.scrollWidth 
          || el.clientHeight < el.scrollHeight;
       el.style.overflow = curOverflow;
       return isOverflowing;
    }
```

here i can find which div is overflowing, but since table was dynamic i don't know the exact ids i tried something like

```
<tr>
        <td>
            <div id="hidden_field_{$row['his_id']}">{$row['his_data']}</div>
         </td>
        <td>
        <br/>
            <?php 
                $check_overflow=echo "<script>checkOverflow(document.getElementById('hidden_field_".{$row['his_id']}."'));</script>";
                if($check_overflow=="true"){
            ?>
            <a id="get_view_more_{$row['his_id']}" onclick="view_more({$row['his_id'];});">View More</a>
            <?php } ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

this function works fine outside php on the bottom of the page

```
<script>
alert(checkOverflow(document.getElementById('hidden_field_1')));</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use ellipsis.

```css
#div2 {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width: 12em; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
#div2:hover {
    width: auto; 
    overflow: visible;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<p>This div uses "text-overflow:ellipsis": when you hover this it's visible</p>
<div id="div2">This is some long text that will not fit in the box</div>
```

just like this way.

Comment: thank you for the solution, i have already done hiding the additional text, what i need i if i have hidden the text there alone i have to show view more option,